# What is the time complexity of SEARCH operation in MongoDB by querying with any index field and with any other field that is not the index?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, mern

I have found that, MongoDB uses **B-tree** that causes **O(log n)** time complexity while searching with any index field like *_id (ObjectId)*. But, does it take **O(n)** time while searching with any field **other than index**?
If not, then what is time taken by it and how is that achieved?

[ Nothing to show here ]

Comment: Are you asking about the time complexity of doing a full scan of the collection?

Comment: What do you mean by a full scan actually?
If it needs a full scan, then it'll take O(n) time (checking one document after another), isn't it? @user20042973

Comment: It's not clear what you intend to search on and what indexes you have. Can you provide a sample query and list of indexes? I agree with what @joe's said in their answer, but it's not clear to me if it applies to the situation you are describing or not

Comment: Suppose that I have a collection named **users** indexed with **__id_** (ObjectId). What are the time complexities of the following search operations?
**(i)** `db.users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId('someID') })` [I know that, it's O(log n)]
**(ii)** `db.users.findOne({ username: 'somename') })` [ does it take O(n) time? Provide some explanation. ] @user20042973

Comment: Yep, O(n). The database has no other option than to scan (up to) every document in the collection

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted to know. But could you give me some genuine resource that described about the complexity or mechanism in which mongoDB handles the search? @user20042973

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity to find a single value in a B-tree of unique values is O(log n) where n is the number of values in the tree.

If you are searching with a single value and an equality match on the `_id` field, that will be O(log n)

If you add an additional criteria that is not in the index, the query executor will first use the index to find potentially matching documents, and will then need an additional matching stage which will examine the documents found by the index scan to apply the additional criteria.

Since the equality search on the `_id` field will yield at most 1 document, the time complexity of the second match stage will be O(1).

If the query is using a ranged search over the `_id` field, finding the first result from the index will be O(log n), then each document after that will be O(1), and the second match stage will need O(m) where m is the number of documents found by the index scan.

Comment: Thanks a lot for describing in detail. But you have only answered the first part, that is, what the complexity is when searching with an index field like __id_.
**For example:** `db.users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId('someID') })`

But what if I have a collection indexed with __id_ but I'm searching with another field **other than __id_** ? What will be the algorithmic complexity of the search operation?
**For example:**
 `db.users.findOne({ username: 'somename' })` @joe

Comment: If you are _only_ querying with un-indexed keys, the time complexity will be O(n) because it will have to load and examine every document in the collection

Comment: Thanks. This is what I want to know. But could you give me some genuine resource that described about the complexity or mechanism in which mongoDB handles the search? @Joe

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of resource you are looking for.  Big O notation describes time complexity in terms of repetitions of some basic unit of work.  When searching for a document in a database, the set of operations necessary to determine if one document matches is used as that base unit.  When searching without an index, every document must be examined separately, so it is O(n) where n is the total number of documents.  This seems tautological, so I'm not sure there will be any specific documentation that explains it.

Comment: It does make sense that searching without any index field would take O(n) time. But I don't understand, why this type of things (like time complexities) are not included in the official documentation. Only the companies which have enough time can read through MongoDB source code to understand how things are done. However, in case of other companies, do programmers write code based on assumptions about how MongoDB handles a specific operation? @Joe

Comment: It is well known that indexes help databases queries perform better.  All the big-O notation is telling you is that finding a single document is a whole bunch faster if you use an index to home in on the document you want rather than search each and every document.   In reality, you can get much more detailed and actionable information from the explain plan.